# Are there any rewards for small community Stack Overflow meetups?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

We are programmers of a small country of Nepal. We do not have the technology to learn – we are all self learners.

We respect Stack Overflow a lot. It helps us to learn and solve problems. Two days ago, Stack Overflow organized a meetup program and we gathered. Five people attended the event. We discussed about how to continue our self-studies and help each other in the field of programming.

Currently, there is no mechanism in Stack Overflow to encourage people just like us. We don't want money or reward – we'd just like some souvenirs. For example pens, stickers, etc. which would give us a stronger feeling towards the site and community.

Comment: I guess that's one way to ask for swag.

Comment: How will pens or stickers help? Why not just get together more often and work on building a strong programming community there, where you can all learn from each other?

Comment: He, [your](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nepal) 147,181 km² is huge compared to [our](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netherlands) 41,528 km² (which even is 18.41% water) ;-)

Comment: @Arjan [mine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel) is the smallest! 22,072 km² - but hey, size doesn't matter.. ;)

Comment: @Sha thanks for support.I just want to know a opinion.Thanks a lot.

Comment: Well, @ShaDowWizArd, 371/km2 [compared to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_and_dependent_territories_by_population_density) our 404!

Comment: +1 to reward you for putting up with these snarky comments. As casper said, kudos on getting your community together!

Comment: (Hoping my comments are not too snarky, as they were surely not intended to be. Happily, @Casper has some powers to clean up, if he feels differently! Off-topic, yeah, I guess.)

Comment: @Arjan Because things *never* get off-topic on meta.  *Never*.

Comment: I was working that day and nobody from the nearby meetup bothered to call 911 to include me...can I get a pen? Emergency services folks love pens.

Comment: its about a human feeling not about the .... friend under stand better.We feel we also a part of stackoverflow and rest of the world.Thanks.

Comment: Initially, I found this entire question to be very odd.  A big reason being that I can't picture myself needing swag, or even any type of feedback at all from other people to reinforce my desire to code.  Maybe, I simply reached a point that the comfort of a successful build outweighs other forms of interaction.  Is it nirvana to utterly and completely grok the Machine Spirit?  Then I remembered that forming a human bond with others on a common journey might be necessary for some to reach this point of enlightenment.  That said, stickers are cool.  Get some and pass them out. ;)

Comment: nop i am not begging P :)

Comment: @ShreeKhanal I emailed you yesterday (to the address you used to create your SO account). If you didn't receive it, please email me (email address is located in my profile).

Comment: @Laura Thanks a lot.I send you a mail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, first off, I'm glad to hear your meetup went well - that's awesome!

We sent out swag packages to some of the largest groups prior to the meetups. I wish we could have sent stuff to everyone, but unfortunately that's impractical (even if we had the resources to track down mailing addresses for everyone, shipping to many parts of the world is... Extremely problematic.)

Laura's gonna get in touch with you to see about setting you guys up with some stickers or something; hopefully you can get together again and pass them out.

For anyone else who had a successful meetup and would like some SO souvenirs to commemorate it, or would simply like to brag a bit... Post your stories and photos on Google+ and tag them #SOMeetup - we'll pick our favorites and include them in a wrap-up on the Stack Overflow blog; if yours is picked, we'll send you a little excuse to get together again.